# How can I send large files from my device to my computer, without using a cable?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, file-transfer

I have a Galaxy S3 (GT-I9300) with 500MB worth of videos on it (2 in total).

I want to transfer those files to my computer. The catch, I have no cable.

How can I transfer those files as quickly and as reliably as possible? Bluetooth isn't an option (it would take hours), can it be done over WiFi? I've tried WiFi direct, it doesn't recognize my PC.

Comment: You can use airdroid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your remote pc has Linux, you could do it through `scp` command.

See [here](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_scp.htm) an explication of the command. You could run this command from a terminal emulator like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en) one.

Short example:
`scp -r path/to/folder user@remote-PC:/path/to/where/to/save/the/files`
`scp path/to/file user@remote-PC:/path/to/remote/location/where/to/save/file`
* `-r` option means recursively copy entire folder.

If your remote pc has windows, take a look at [pscp](http://www.nber.org/pscp.html).

---

Another way is to install [**ES File Explorer File Manager**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en). 
* Select the local files you wish to transfer (actions -> copy) 
* In LAN section access a folder from your remote PC and paste (actions -> paste) the selected files.
* The folder from remote pc has to be shared with write permission.

Comment: I'm afraid my PC has no Linux, it's a Windows machine. Thanks for your answer anyway!

Comment: _If your remote pc has windows, take a look at pscp._

Comment: How do I use it with a phone? (I'm not an expert with UNIX systems)

Comment: Don't make it that difficult. If you've got normal WiFi at home, and created at least one "shared folder" at your Windows machine, take a look at the [ES File Explorer File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop). It has an auto-discover option which finds the share, and then you can copy, browse, and whatever however how long you want to :)

Comment: @Izzy For me `scp` is the easy way. :)

Comment: @Ovidiu Yeah, and `rsync` is also fine. And I write my eBooks using a plain text editor, and do a lot of things from the command line. But for a simple Windows user, there must be icons to click -- and they get shocked when there's nothing but a black screen with a prompt where one is expected to *type in commands* :) Which means, in short: different people -- different solutions.

Comment: @Izzy could you please add that as an answer? ES worked for me

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I gladly would -- but see above: Ovidiu already included it with this answer, together with some details on how to use it and even some hints on possible "traps" to avoid, so I see nothing to add to it (if you do, feel free to suggest and I will do!). Glad it worked out for you!

Comment: @Ovidiu: It would probably be best if you put your two separate suggestions into different answers. Then each could be evaluated (and voted on) by its own merits.

Comment: Well, i was working on stg also and didn't see Izzy's comment. Glad if either one of the answers/comments helped your transfer those files.

Answer (score 2):

I use [WiFi File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dooblou.WiFiFileExplorerPRO) for this sort of thing.  There are free and paid versions.  The app acts as a web server showing the file system as a web page with all the nessasary options to copy to and from another device viewing the website.  You browse to it over the wifi link.  Works really well although for a really big transfer plugging the cable is is faster.

It will be a year or two befor we start to get phones with [802.11ad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11#802.11ad) style wifi with multi gigabit wifi speeds which will make this a doddle.